# stream seekg() implementation varies from VS2012 to 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, stream

I've an old piece of code that works well on gcc, VS2010. I was trying to compile the same in VS2012. I know  I'vent set done to true anywhere, but its not the actual code. I've shortened the code to reproduce the problem.

```
std::ifstream file_stream;
file_stream.open("C:\\experiment\\file.txt", std::ios_base::in);
std::istream& stream = file_stream;
bool done = false;
while(stream.good() || !done){
    int stream_position = stream.tellg();
    bool stream_failure = (stream_position == -1);
    bool stream_eof = stream.eof();
    std::string line;
    std::getline(stream, line);

    std::cout << stream_failure << stream_eof << std::endl;

    std::streampos pos = stream.tellg();
    if(pos == std::streampos(-1)){
        std::streampos copy = pos;
        stream.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
        pos = stream.tellg();
        stream.seekg(copy);
    }
}
std::getline(std::cin, std::string());
file_stream.close();
```

If I change platform toolset to VS2010 it works and prints `1` in place of `stream_eof`
If I change platform toolset to VS2012 it doesn't and prints `0` in place of `stream_eof`
after it has reached EOF

If I put a `if(stream_eof)return 0;` after cout it returns on VS2010 but doesn't return in VS2012

Comment: "works well on gcc" --- not for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one of the differences between C++03 and C++11.

In C++03, when you call `seekg()` on a stream which has any error bits set, it fails and does nothing else.

In C++11, `seekg()` first unconditionally clears the `eofbit`, and then attempts to do as told. In this case, since `failbit` is also set, it fails, but `eofbit` is left cleared.

(incidentally, why is your loop set up to read past the end of file in the first place? Use the usual `while(getline(stream, line))`)

Comment: I don't remember why I coded it this way, actually sometimes the main parser outsources the stream to this function, may be the main parser was facing problem when the internal function hits eof and this was an work around. But whats the work around now to make it work on both ? and I checked and surprised why seekg() clears eof bit ?

Comment: @Neel Basu It clears it (as of C++11) to make it possible to seek away from the end of file without extra work, which is a common use case.